# Getting TypeError upon initilizing ManagementClient in Auth0

Tags: auth0

I am trying to initialize Auth0  ManagementClient in my Lambda function (Node.js + Typescript)

```
import { ManagementClient } from "auth0";

private getAuth0Client() {
    const auth0Domain = process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN;
    const auth0ClientId = process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID;
    const auth0ClientSecret = process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET;
    
    if(auth0Domain && auth0ClientId && auth0ClientSecret) {
        return new ManagementClient({
            domain: auth0Domain,
            clientId: auth0ClientId,
            clientSecret: auth0ClientSecret,
            scope: "read:users update:users",
        });
    } else {
        throw new Error("Could not initialize Auth0 Management Client");
    }
}

public async getUser(userId: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const auth0Client = this.getAuth0Client();
        return await auth0Client.getUser({
            id: userId
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

and it gives me the following error

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "E is not a function",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError: E is not a function",
        "    at Object.91738 (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:94:5226)",
        "    at ds (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2333:1904531)",
        "    at Object.59458 (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:94:15606)",
        "    at ds (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2333:1904531)",
        "    at Object.16135 (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2220:1079)",
        "    at ds (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2333:1904531)",
        "    at Object.81557 (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2173:10664)",
        "    at ds (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2333:1904531)",
        "    at Object.96781 (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2173:15330)",
        "    at ds (/var/task/src/sns-lambda.js:2333:1904531)"
    ]
}
```

I am using the following versions for auth0

`auth0: 3.3.0` and `@types/auth0: 2.35.9`

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Hey, did you find the solution to this problem?